# Add more degrees everytime you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, transform

I want to add more degrees of rotation to #rad-spin every time someone clicks on #rad-btn

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rad-btn").click(function(){
        $("#rad-spin").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
    });
});
```

Now it just goes one time to 90deg and if I click again it won't go further to 180deg (obviously). That's what I want.. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. By lexical scope, you can do this.By this, keep the outer value `index`.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var index = 0
     $("#rad-btn").click(function(){
       index++
       $("#rad-spin").css("transform", "rotate(" + 90 * index + "deg)");
     });
   });
   ```
2. By `data-` and `$.data`, you can save the info in the DOM.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#rad-spin").data('index', 0)
     $("#rad-btn").click(function(){
       var index = $("#rad-spin").data('index')
       $("#rad-spin").data('index', ++index)
       $("#rad-spin").css("transform", "rotate(" + 90 * index + "deg)");
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Now I have another problem though. I want the button: #rad-btn. To be disabled while it's spinning.. (It's a spinning-wheel btw) ivoklerk.com/sesamestreet/rad.html# – user3124133 just now   edit

Comment: I cannot get your aim.User may multiple click the `#rad-btn` before the animate end? @user3124133

Comment: No while it's spinning the user should not be able to click. Now it's spinning faster and faster if you click multiple times. The button to start the spinning again should be clickable only before and after the animation.

Comment: I cannot add much code here, from my idea, 1. you should hidden the `#rad-btn` in the `click` listener. 2. you should add listener to [event transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) of `#rad-spin`.When the transition end,  you can let the btn show. @user3124133

Answer (score 1):

Just store the angle somewhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var angle = 0;
    $("#rad-btn").click(function(){
        angle+=720;
        $("#rad-spin").css("transform", "rotate("+angle+"deg)");
        $(this).prop('disabled',true).delay(2000).queue(()=>$(this).prop('disabled',false).dequeue());
    });
});
```

```css
#rad-spin{
  transition: transform 2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='rad-btn'>v. rad</button>
<div id='rad-spin'>spin me round and round</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it already with TomIsion's solution. Now I have another problem though. I want the button: #rad-btn. To be disabled while it's spinning.. (It's a spinning-wheel btw)

http://ivoklerk.com/sesamestreet/rad.html#

Comment: various ways to do this, I added one into my answer. You define a transition timeout in css, disable the button and then enable it after the same delay on click.